# How to find scope level with token_get_all()?

Tags: php, parsing, tokenize

I'm using token_get_all() to do some static analysis on a php project.

How do I find the scope level for stuff like:

- Finding if the current T_FUNCTION is still inside the T_CLASS being parsed
- Knowing if the scope for T_VARIABLE has already ended

Should I keep a count of '{' and '}' characters? Is that a safe method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might do better to use a parser to build a syntax tree, otherwise the edge cases will become very complex (PHP is a very tricky language that can have other languages embedded in it).

A quick google came up with: [PHP-Parser](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser)

With a syntax tree you could more easily identify the scope of a function or variable, but it would still require some analysis.

Comment: This project is experimental. Also it doesn't help me much. Thank's anyway.

Comment: It's now been +2 years and PHP-Parser is much more mature. I'm using it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The `token_get_all()` is exactly what the package says: it's a tokenizer.

This means that you have to keep track of scope yourself, by keeping track of opening and closing braces; the simplest way I can think of is to build a [recursive descent parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser).

Btw, parse errors would already be handled by this function.